# Setting NODE_ENV via envify not working

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I have the following `gulp` task in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
    gulp.task('build-scripts', function () {
    var b = browserify({ debug: false });
    b.transform(reactify);
    b.transform(envify({
        _: 'purge',
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }));

    b.add('./src/scripts/index.js');

    return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('./www/scripts/dist/bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))

});
```

The task completes with status 0 and the `React` transform happens, but in `bundle.js` I still see:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
```

Wasn't this supposed to go away with the `envify` transform?
Am I doing something wrong here?

I have done some digging, but all the solutions I can find are os x / linux specific (I'm on a windows machine).

**EDIT:** I am running the gulp build from within visual studio's `Task Runner Explorer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc says:

> By default, environment variables that are not defined will be left untouched.

https://github.com/hughsk/envify#purging-processenv

Have you tried defining it before running that? i.e.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```